# WPF DependencyProperty... now it works... now it doesn't... how come?

Tags: wpf, callback, dependency-properties

I have a ClockFace UserControl that exposes a number of properties to enable users to style it. The clock has two Ellipse objects as borders; an outer border and an inner border.

```
<Ellipse Name="OuterBorder" Panel.ZIndex="5" StrokeThickness="{Binding BorderOuterThickness}" Stroke="{Binding BorderOuteBrush}" />
<Ellipse Name="InnerBorder" Panel.ZIndex="6" StrokeThickness="{Binding BorderInnerThickness}" Margin="{Binding StrokeThickness, ElementName=OuterBorder}" Stroke="{Binding BorderInnerBrush}">

public static readonly DependencyProperty BorderInnerBrushProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BorderInnerBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(ClockFace), new 

PropertyMetadata(new LinearGradientBrush(Color.FromRgb(118, 57, 57), Color.FromRgb(226, 185, 185), new Point(0.5, 0), new Point(0.5, 1))));

public Brush BorderInnerBrush
{
    get { return (Brush)GetValue(BorderInnerBrushProperty); }
    set { SetValue(BorderInnerBrushProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty BorderOuterBrushProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BorderOuterBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(ClockFace), new 

PropertyMetadata(new LinearGradientBrush(Color.FromRgb(226, 185, 185), Color.FromRgb(118, 57, 57), new Point(0.5, 0), new Point(0.5, 1))));

public Brush BorderOuterBrush
{
    get { return (Brush)GetValue(BorderOuterBrushProperty); }
    set { SetValue(BorderOuterBrushProperty, value); }
}
```

These can be set in a style and will update correctly when the styles are switched. I thought that I would be clever and add a shortcut property called BorderBrush that passes itself to the BorderOuterBrush property and then passes a copy of itself with its gradient reversed to the BorderInnerBrush property. To enable this code to run when the property was set after initialisation (by switching styles), I had to implement a PropertyChangedCallback method that calls the SetBorderBrushes method.

```
public new static readonly DependencyProperty BorderBrushProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BorderBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(ClockFace), new 

PropertyMetadata(OnBorderBrushChanged));

private static void OnBorderBrushChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((ClockFace)dependencyObject).SetBorderBrushes((Brush)e.NewValue);
}

public new Brush BorderBrush
{
    get { return (Brush)GetValue(BorderBrushProperty); }
    set { SetValue(BorderBrushProperty, value); }
}

private void SetBorderBrushes(Brush brush)
{
    if (brush != null)
    {
        BorderOuterBrush = brush;
        Brush innerBrush = BorderOuterBrush.Clone();
        if (brush.GetType() == typeof(LinearGradientBrush) || brush.GetType() == typeof(RadialGradientBrush))
        {
            foreach (GradientStop gradientStop in ((GradientBrush)innerBrush).GradientStops)
            {
                gradientStop.Offset = 1 - gradientStop.Offset;
            }
        }
        BorderInnerBrush = innerBrush;
    }
}
```

When the BorderBrush property is set in a style, it all works just fine... that is until I switch the style at run time. Now the strangest thing happens... let me explain.

I have four preset styles and individually, they all work just fine. Three of them use the two BorderInnerBrush and BorderOuterBrush properties and one uses the shortcut BorderBrush property. I can switch between the styles using a ContextMenu and some code behind that accesses the xaml styles from Resources and sets them to the ClockFace object's Style property.

I can switch between the three styles that don't use the shortcut property endlessly without problem. I can also switch to the style that does use the shortcut property and it appears just fine. This is when the strangeness begins.

After switching to the style that uses the BorderBrush property, the BorderInnerBrush and BorderOuterBrush properties simply stop working. The preset Brush objects set in the various styles no longer get set on the two Ellipse objects. I pluged in some PropertyChangedCallback methods to the inner and outer border properties to see what was going on.

When I first run the application, I can switch to the three styles that don't use the shortcut property without problem. I put breakpoints on all three border Brush properties' PropertyChangedCallback methods and debugged the program. When switching to each of these three styles, the inner and outer border properties' callback methods' breakpoints were hit as you would expect. When switching to the style that uses the BorderBrush property, its callback method's breakpoint was hit. The SetBorderBrushes method sets the two other border Brush objects so the inner and outer border properties' callback methods' breakpoints were then hit as you would expect.

Again, this is the weird part. When switching to any of the other three styles after this, the inner and outer border properties' callback methods' breakpoints are no longer hit at all. Instead, the breakpoint in the callback method attached to the BorderBrush property is hit an the value of e.NewValue is null. As null values are ignored in the SetBorderBrushes method, no further breakpoints are hit.

After further investigation, I discovered that the e.NewValue was null because there was no default value set on the BorderBrushProperty DependencyProperty. Indeed, after adding a default Brush object to the declaration, this is the Brush that would be passed in e.NewValue in the callback method. Although the breakpoints in the two inner and outer border properties' callback methods would get hit after this, it was only because they are set in the SetBorderBrushes method. The Brush objects set in the BorderInnerBrush and BorderOuterBrush objects in the styles never get passed to these properties after the BorderBrush property has been used once.

One final point to note is that just as the default value of the BorderBrushProperty property is set when a value is not explicitly set in a style, the default values of the inner and outer border DependencyProperty objects are also set when their values are not explicitly set in a style, but only when the BorderBrush property is not also set in the style.

I've been stuck on this for days now and although an easy solution would be to remove the shortcut property, I'd rather find out what's going on and fix it. I hope I've provided enough information for some bright spark to be able to solve this problem, so, if you have any ideas or questions, please share them. Many thanks.

UPDATE >>

Following Rick's suggestion,  I created another pair of Brush properties and set them from the callback methods attached to the other three Brush properties. Using this setup, I could switch between all of the styles without any visual problems... or so I thought.

I can now switch from the style that uses the BorderBrush (shortcut) property to the styles that set the two BorderInner and BorderOuter properties and the borders update correctly, so thanks Rick for getting me one step closer. I still have a problem when switching from the style that sets the BorderBrush property to the style that does not explicitly set any border Brush.

Therefore, I still have the same problem that the BorderInnerBrush and BorderOuterBrush properties don't work directly after being set from code behind. What's new is that if I then switch to a style that sets the two Brush properties, this seems to 'wake them up' again... if I then switch to the style that sets no border Brush, the inner and outer properties set their default values correctly again.

It's only after using a style that sets the two border properties from code behind that they become dead to being set in styles or using their default values. This is so strange... can anyone work it out?

UPDATE 2 >>>

First, thanks so much for your time and example Rick. After copying and pasting Rick's example code into a new project, I had to make a few alterations before it would run... maybe because I don't have Expression Blend 4? I installed the SDK and added the references to the noted dlls, but had to use the following XML namespace declarations instead:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:ei="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"
```

I also had to change each ChangePropertyAction declaration slightly to:

```
<ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="clock" PropertyName="Style" Value="{StaticResource styleBrush}"/>
```

Then, it worked fine for me and is a good representation of that portion of my actual ClockFace control, with two exceptions. The first is that my styles are switched from code behind via an event handler - this is clearly not causing my problem. The second difference is that I have set default Brush values on my versions of ActualOuterBrush and ActualInnerBrush, so that users of the control don't have to supply border brushes.

So my final problem is that the default inner and outer border brushes do not get set in a Style with no border properties explicitly set after the BorderBrush property has been set in a Style. Remember, the default values do get set up until this point. So, I experimented with Rick's example and added some default values:

```
private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey ActualInnerBrushPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("ActualInnerBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(Clock), new UIPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Teal));

private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey ActualOuterBrushPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("ActualOuterBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(Clock), new UIPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Salmon));
```

Now this project has a similar problem... the default values are never reset. I'm so baffled by this behaviour.

I've spent so long stuck on this problem now and although I have learned a number of useful things from Rick, I still have this problem with the default values. I've decided that the simplest thing to do is to remove the shortcut BorderBrush property. Rick has helped so much that I am awarding his answer as the correct answer, but if anyone reading this can help with the default value, I'd be grateful to hear from them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once a property has been set, styles no longer will be applied.  By setting the inner and outer brush properties in your changed handler yourself, the dependency property subsystem is not aware that the the change was actually due to a style versus you doing it explicitly.

One solution is to expose protected read-only `ActualInnerBorderBrush` and `ActualOuterBorderBrush` properties and then have all three of the user-definable properties set these actual values in their respective change handlers.  This way the user-visible properties can always be "as set by the user" without interfering with each other.

**Edit:**

Here is a complete working implementation of the five properties:

```
public class Clock : StackPanel
{
    public Brush Brush
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(BrushProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BrushProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BrushProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Brush", typeof(Brush), typeof(Clock),
        new UIPropertyMetadata((d, e) => (d as Clock).OnBrushChanged(d, e)));

    public void OnBrushChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ActualInnerBrush = e.NewValue as Brush;
        ActualOuterBrush = e.NewValue as Brush;
    }

    public Brush InnerBrush
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(InnerBrushProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InnerBrushProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty InnerBrushProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("InnerBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(Clock),
        new UIPropertyMetadata((d, e) => (d as Clock).OnInnerBrushChanged(d, e)));

    public void OnInnerBrushChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ActualInnerBrush = e.NewValue as Brush;
    }

    public Brush OuterBrush
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(OuterBrushProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OuterBrushProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty OuterBrushProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("OuterBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(Clock),
        new UIPropertyMetadata((d, e) => (d as Clock).OnOuterBrushChanged(d, e)));

    public void OnOuterBrushChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ActualOuterBrush = e.NewValue as Brush;
    }

    public Brush ActualInnerBrush
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(ActualInnerBrushProperty); }
        private set { SetValue(ActualInnerBrushPropertyKey, value); }
    }

    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey ActualInnerBrushPropertyKey =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("ActualInnerBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(Clock), new UIPropertyMetadata());
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ActualInnerBrushProperty = ActualInnerBrushPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;


    public Brush ActualOuterBrush
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(ActualOuterBrushProperty); }
        private set { SetValue(ActualOuterBrushPropertyKey, value); }
    }

    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey ActualOuterBrushPropertyKey =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("ActualOuterBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(Clock), new UIPropertyMetadata());
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ActualOuterBrushProperty = ActualOuterBrushPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;
}
```

and here is a little test program to prove that it works:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="styleBrush" TargetType="local:Clock">
            <Setter Property="Brush" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="styleInnerOnly" TargetType="local:Clock">
            <Setter Property="InnerBrush" Value="Green"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="styleInnerOuter" TargetType="local:Clock">
            <Setter Property="InnerBrush" Value="Blue"/>
            <Setter Property="OuterBrush" Value="Yellow"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="styleEmpty" TargetType="local:Clock"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <local:Clock x:Name="clock" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="{Binding ActualInnerBrush, ElementName=clock}"/>
            <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="{Binding ActualOuterBrush, ElementName=clock}"/>
        </local:Clock>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Default">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                        <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=clock}" PropertyName="Style" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Button>
            <Button Content="BrushOnly">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                        <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=clock}" PropertyName="Style" Value="{StaticResource styleBrush}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Button>
            <Button Content="InnerOnly">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                        <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=clock}" PropertyName="Style" Value="{StaticResource styleInnerOnly}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Button>
            <Button Content="InnerOuter">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                        <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=clock}" PropertyName="Style" Value="{StaticResource styleInnerOuter}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Button>
            <Button Content="Empty">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                        <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=clock}" PropertyName="Style" Value="{StaticResource styleEmpty}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

This example uses behaviors.  If you are not familiar with behaviors, install the Expression Blend 4 SDK and add these namespaces:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

and add `System.Windows.Interactivity` and `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions` to your project.

Comment: I tried your solution and am sorry to say that it didn't fix my border problem. I created another pair of Brush properties and set them from the other 3. Using this setup, I could switch between all of the styles without any visual problems... The problem is that my Ellipse objects bind to the Brush properties, so they must be public... then a user could set them and I would have the same problem.

Comment: No problem: Then make it public read-only!  The only reason I suggested protected was so that they wouldn't appear in the IntelliSense list of your consumers.  To create a read-only dependency property use `DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly` and use a private setter.

Comment: The callback is only called when the value changes and if the property has a value then a style setter has no effect and so the value remains unchanged.  So the reason the value gets stuck and the reason the property changed handler appears to stop being called are due to the same cause: styles cannot override explicitly set values.

Comment: oh gosh, I just updated the post, but I should have waited... you just answered my main question and I'm happy to give you the credit, but can you help with my final problem? (See update section in post)

Comment: once again thank you so much for taking the time to provide such a full answer. I absolutely love your use of Lambda expresions to allow the callback methods to be non static. Unfortunately, even your implementation doesn't fix my final problem. Please see my post update 2 for further details.